# To detect character written after "@" in TextView +iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitextview

In Text-view I want to detect the character written after "@" charachter

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
if([txt_comment.text isEqualToString:@"@"]){

     }      
    return YES;

}
```

But I'm able to catch the event once I write "@" character. How to detect the event and the character written after "@"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
    if (isCharacterBefore) {
        NSLog(@"the Character after @ is %@",text);
        isCharacterBefore = NO;
    }
    if([text isEqualToString:@"@"]){
        isCharacterBefore = YES;
    } 

    return YES;

}
```

Here `isCharacterBefore` is a `BOOL` variable declared in .h file.
Hope it Help's you.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
if ([txt_comment.text rangeOfString:@"@"].location == NSNotFound) 
{
   NSLog(@"string does not contain @");
}
else 
{
   NSLog(@"string contains @!");
   /* What ever you want to do Write here */
   NSArray *tempArray = [txt_comment.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
   if([tempArray count] >= 2 && [tempArray objectAtIndex:1]! = NULL)
   {
      NSLog(@"%@",[tempArray objectAtIndex:1]);
   }
}
}
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentsSeparatedByString:` in your string

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
   NSArray *arr = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
   if([arr count] == 2)
      NSLog(@"Your String After @ %@",[arr objectAtIndex:1]);
   else
       NSLog(@"@ string not found");

   return YES;
 }
```